# Why doesn't my live USB save settings, even though I have a persistence file?

Tags: live-usb, persistence

I have just made a Live USB of Ubuntu 12.04 on a 4 GB stick. I made it in startup disk creator in 10.04 and set the persistence file to 3 GB.

But for some reason it doesn't save my settings on shutdown when I use it with my Macbook Pro. Otherwise it works just fine though. Any ideas why it doesn't save my settings?